# Open existing nvidia-docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and docker and I am trying to make a docker container where I can use tensorflow with GPU.

After trying different things I managed to set up my nvidia drivers and I can run:

```
nvidia-docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow bash
```

which opens me a docker container with a tensorflow image.

This is good as it creates me the tensorflow docker container where I can install also keras and use it, but if I exit from this container I loose all my created files and installed packages.

How is it possible once I exit this container to go back to it and have all my files and packages still in there?

Below is a screenshot with my docker images (which are too many now because of my many tries to go around this issue and because some tensorflow images did not install properly):

[image]

I hope there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: It might be worth it to either a) create your own docker image on top of the `gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow` using custom `Dockerfile`, or b) use `docker commit` to "save" current state of your container into new image. That way you don't have to install `keras` and other libs each time you spin up a new container. Does this sound like something you would need?

Comment: They both are interesting methods, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nvidia-docker run -it` create **NEW** container

you want to open existed container use

`nvidia-docker start -i CONTAINER_ID` or
`nvidia-docker start -i NAMES`

and if you want more terminals
`nvidia-docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` or
`nvidia-docker exec -it NAMES bash`

**Update**
Run container when the container is close

```
$ docker ps -a                                                                                                  [ruby-2.3.1p112]
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
acd83fb407b4        rfcn:rfcn           "/bin/bash"         4 days ago          Exited (0) 28 hours ago                       rfcn
$ nvidia-docker start -i rfcn                                                                                   [ruby-2.3.1p112]
root@acd83fb407b4:/#
```

Open another terminal when the container is running

```
$ nvidia-docker exec -it rfcn bash                                                                              [ruby-2.3.1p112]
root@acd83fb407b4:/#
```

Comment: I tried it and it works if I have the container opened in a terminal to open it again in another terminal, but if I close it then I can't open it again. I get the error Error response from daemon: Container Container_Id is not running and that Container_Id disappears from the docker containers list.

Comment: sorry, my fault, it should be `start`. update answer, please check

Comment: I ran docker exec -it Container_Id and it worked like that, but on an older container. The nvidia-docker version still does not work even if I user start instead of exec

Comment: Ummm, sorry again. I didn't test before edit post. it is `start -i`, I test the command, I hope it fine now.

Comment: I have also discovered just now that if I restart my computer and then run docker ps my container is not there anymore. Are docker containers temporary?

Comment: NO, container is permanent unless you delete it, you can see my container `rfcn` was created 4 days ago